# What are the default permissions on the Debian /etc/passwd file?

Tags: debian, permissions, passwd

What are the default permissions for /etc/passwd on Debian distributions?

Comment: If you have changed the permissions and/or ownership of `/etc/passwd`, have you also done the same on other files and/or directories on the system?

Answer (score 3):

It should have read permission allowed for all users (many utilities, like ls(1) use it to map user IDs to usernames), but write access only for the superuser.

From passwd man
https://linux.die.net/man/5/passwd

Comment: so the permission is 644?

Comment: @Alaa Yeah, that's right.

Comment: Note there are no passwords in the password file, so it is safe for all to read. There are password hashes (one way encrypted) in `/etc/shadow`.